# PHP and DRUPAL, Cannot save values in a static variable and pass through function

Tags: php, drupal

Developing a module for drupal and I need to pass/modify variables within functions. I avoided using global variables because drupal uses the include function which subsequently makes my global variable into local.

As such, i created the following script which stores a static variable but I cannot retain the new value. Any help will be appreciated

```
function _example_set_flashurl($value = '21224', $clear = NULL) {
  static $url;

  if ($clear) {
    // reset url variable back to default
    $url = null;
  }
  // assigned url a perminate value within this function
  $url = $value;
  return $url;


}

function _example_get_flashurl() {
  return _example_set_flashurl();
  // retrieve the value inside set scope
}
_example_set_flashurl('another', TRUE);
print _example_get_flashurl();  // prints 21224,  I want it to print another
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?
function _example_set_flashurl($value = '21224', $clear = NULL) {
  static $url;

  if ($clear) {
    // reset url variable back to default
    $url = null;
  }
  if($value!='21224') {
  // assigned url a perminate value within this function
  $url = $value;
  }
  return $url;


}

function _example_get_flashurl() {
  return _example_set_flashurl();
  // retrieve the value inside set scope
}
_example_set_flashurl('another', TRUE);
print _example_get_flashurl();  // prints 21224,  I want it to print another
```

Answer (score 0):

You override the value in the empty call to set in your get function.

First, you probably want to add the default value directly to the static and not the argument. Like this: "static $url = '21224';". Then, this value will also be returned when set has never been called.

Second, there is no need for a $clear argument if you can pass in any value you want. If you want to change it, just override the old value.

Third, as the answer from bruce dou showed, you want to protect it against accidently overriding the value.

So, this code for the set function should be all you need:

```
<?php
function _example_set_flashurl($value = FALSE) {
  static $url = '21224';

  // Only keep value if it's not FALSE.
  if ($value !== FALSE) {
    // assigned url a perminate value within this function
    $url = $value;
  }
  return $url;
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks, all both solution worked fine. BUt it only works if i am passing my variables in the "same page"  By that I mean setting and getting variable between two different functions from the same page load.  But i am passing these variable through ajax request and when i print the variable - $url. it prints 21224.

Comment: I've only managed to get this working through variable_set and variable_get. but this is a performance issue since it clear the table every time variable_Set is used. Any other suggestion? global doesnt work either, it spits the default value

Comment: This is by design. PHP is stateless, nothing is shared between requests. If it is user-specific, you can save it in $_SESSION. And yes, variable_get/set is meant for "write once (more or less)/read often" stuff.

Comment: makes sense .. Users accessing these functions and variables are either anonymous or registered users so Im not sure how $_Session would work for the former. i  did look into other modules and they've used database together with cache mechanisim  ..it is something i'll have to look into as well.   (The endless joy of programming eh -_- )

Comment: Alright, after 2 days I finally got it working. Thanks Berdir you really brought light into my design by mentioning that PHP is stateless. I solved the issue by using cache_set and cache_get. For anyone out there looking for a more details about these two god send function head to http://www.lullabot.com/articles/a-beginners-guide-to-caching-data